# Travis - Require PHP ext-simplexml in Composer

Tags: php, travis-ci

I am trying to require `"ext-SimpleXML": "^7.1"` in my `composer.json` and I am using travis as my testing framework. Locally everything works fine but on travis (when using `composer install`) I always get the error message:

```
The requested PHP extension ext-simplexml ^7.1 has the wrong version (0.1) installed. Install or enable PHP's simplexml extension.
```

Does anyone know how I can update or tell travis to install/use the correct version? I already tried it with `sudo apt-get install php-xml` without success.

Comment: Regarding `sudo apt-get install php-xml`, what error message did you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try use the line below.

```
"ext-SimpleXML": "*"
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#platform-packages

Most of PHP extensions do not have own versions. They are fixed to a specific PHP build. Few are a thin shims to system libraries and the shims versions are meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but do they still support the same functionality?

Comment: I have updated an answer a little. The official PHP libraries have a very good backward compatibility. You can assume that if PHP version is good, the library works too. The bigger problem is different configurations.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help! My build now ran successfully and locally everything seems fine :).